# Why does Google show different search results when viewed by 10 versus 100 results per page?

Tags: google-search, search-results

Most of the time I have seen that when I enter my query in Google's search box and view the results by 10 per page, and then with the same query I view the results by 100 per page, the results are very dissimilar after the fifth position.

Does Google use any kind of filter during instant results when viewed by 10 per page, and why would viewing by 100 per page have different SERP results?

Comment: Can you give an example? Are you searching in the same window (neighbouring tabs)? Which browser? I just tried 3 different searches in Google Chrome (Windows) and the results were identical for the first 20 positions (ignoring the occasional paid advert). I did have an instance when two positions on the "instant search" were reversed (positions 7 and 8 I think - in the first 20), but these "corrected" themselves when repeating the search. (I'm also logged into Google during the test.)

Comment: Is this related to your own website somehow?   Questions about how Google works can be OK here, but only if they relate to running your own website.

Comment: Hi Stephen,
 
Thanks for your attention at my query. The query I am searching with is “Yahoo Customer Service” for url “http://www.yahoocustomerservice.org”.
 
There are two cases:
 
Ist Case is, if I do check in 10 results in SERP then this site is nowhere or sometimes comes after 100 results.
2nd Case is, when I do check in 100 SERP results, then site does come at 7th position, this is a huge gap.
 
FYI, I am already checking in incognito window without login into any Google account, also confirmed this gap in Firefox, chrome and opera
 
Thanks.

Comment: FYI, yahoocustomerservice.org is not my own, It's a third party site for providing tech support for yahoo issues, I had paid for their services earlier, and they are very good for their services. And all these happening with email-customercare.com site also.

Comment: Can confirm this is the usual behavior. I'm checking the SERPs most days and there are often differences when on view 100.  You get pages appearing that don't normally appear at all when on view 10 per page. I don't know why this is though.

Comment: Even I don't know why this much difference in results. Does Anyone get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of filters in place, here are the two that are most likely in effect:

1. User filters are applied to try and make search results more relevant to your history. It could be that an advanced search is 'hiding private results'. There's a button to replicate this if you're logged into Google, in the top-right of the display.
2. Google will hide results that rate highly for your query but that have received a low relevancy score because they're repeated or similar to other results. Again, an advanced search may be switching this filter off.

In the end - Google is an enigma wrapped in a mystery. I've read all their patents, studied their system and SEO is my job. Yet I'll never fully comprehend how it works, it changes too often to be certain of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any particular filter Google use when you see the top 100 results instead of 10 results. Its happened by default